# Web page linking to SQL2000 - taking too long to fully load

Tags: html, sql, web, asp-classic, vbscript

I have an internal web page that connects to an SQL2000 database, pulls the data and then displays it on a table. The SQL query takes on average 3 seconds to get the full results (in this instance 59 rows).

```
select Call_Ref, per_data7, dbo.dateonly(Scheduled_Date_Time) as sched_date, Call_Status_Description, Add1, Add2, Post_Code, contract_short_name, Call_Type_Description, LUCFC_Description, sched_colour_code
from Calls with (nolock)
    inner join Clients with (nolock) on Link_to_Client=Client_Ref
    left join Personnel with (nolock) on Last_Allocated_To=Pers_Ref
    left join LU_Call_Types with (nolock) on Call_Type=Call_Type_Code
    left join Personnel_More with (nolock) on Last_Allocated_To=PER_Link_to_Pers_Ref
    left join LU_Call_Fault_codes with (nolock) on call_fault_code_1=LUCFC_Code
    left join LU_Call_Status with (nolock) on Last_Event_Status=Call_Status_Code
    left join call_more on call_ref=callm_link_to_call
    left join contractids on link_to_contract_header=contract_ref
where dbo.dateonly(Scheduled_Date_Time) between '09/09/2013' and '13/09/2013'
    and Call_Type in ('BC','IN')
    and PER_Data7 in ('Team 1','Team 2','Team 3','Team 4','Team 5','Team 6','Team 7','Team 8','Team 9','Team 10','Gas1')
    and Call_Status_Description in ('Allocated','Reported Done','Complete')
or CALLM_Data21 between '19/08/2013' and '23/08/2013'
    and CALLM_Data22 in ('Team 1','Team 2','Team 3','Team 4','Team 5','Team 6','Team 7','Team 8','Team 9','Team 10','Gas1')
    and link_to_contract_header = 'BGAS-1'
    and call_type not in ('BC','IN')
    and call_status_description not in ('Cancelled')
order by per_data7, dbo.dateonly(Scheduled_Date_Time)
```

I am then displaying those results in a table, using do/while loops and if statements to filter the results into where they should be displayed in the table - the problem is that each of those takes an additional 3 seconds to display - thus the complete web page takes around 3 and half minutes to fully load (i had to extend the timeout to allow to fully load).

I need to get this down to a usable amount of time.

The webserver is Windows IIS and the web page is basic html, classic-asp with some VB.
It server also has PHP installed, but i am not sure which version.

I have attached the files in a ZIP for anyone to look at.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/qbfp0cswo403e4u/files.zip

So, guys.... what can I do to get this page to load in a timescale that makes it actually usable?

A viewable version of the page is here `http://195.171.121.111/week0909-test.asp` which I will leave there for a day or so.

Comment: Could you test your query without the dbo.dateonly function in it? Use the field Scheduled_Date_Time instead. I suspect that this UDF is causing your problems.

Comment: i can try that, here's hoping it chops over 3 minutes off the query time, but i'm not hopeful

Comment: that's improved the speed quite a bit, however my IF statements now don't work as the scheduled_date_time is no longer just date, but now also included a time that varies depending on the job.

<%IF teamjobs.Fields("sched_date").value = "09/09/2013" and teamjobs.Fields("PER_Data7").value = "Team 1" THEN%>

so how do i compensate for that?

Comment: This code looks like it is generated by other code? Is that possible?

Comment: Try the function in just the select clause, and not in the where or order by clauses to see if the performance drops badly or not. i suspect it would have been in the where or order by clauses that it has the most impact.

Comment: what code?
all the code has been manually created, nothing auto generated by anything else.

Comment: See if this matches the date: cdate(teamjobs.Fields("sched_date").value) = cdate("09/09/2013")

Comment: yes, it was the the function in the WHERE clause that was slowing it down. have left it in the SELECT clause and the speed has improved greatly

Comment: OK this has improved the load speed from 3m 30s to 58s.
Could still be doing with improving it even more though.

Comment: How long does a single run of the query take?

Comment: a single run of the query take between 1 and 2 seconds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user defined function function in the where and order by clause is probably causing the slow-down for SQL.

You should be able to pull the query data once, and then build up in memory hashes of the Teams and Dates. Another hash should contain lists of the entries for a cross hash between the  team and dates, then you can just iterate over the data set once instead of (team-names.count * dates.count) times.

Comment: OK removing the dbo.dateonly functions has improved the load speed from 3m 30s to 58s.
Could still be doing with improving it even more though.

Comment: got no idea about memory hashes though

Comment: try this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/3cng0o42l0em03m/week0909-test.asp (working from memory here, so cut me some slack for any syntax errors)

Comment: just spotted the dates array was wrong (was set to august dates), changed it to the correct dates and now shows the data, but the data that should be in the thrusday column is in the friday column

Comment: have sorted this now, seems to be loading very quickly indeed!

Comment: Should be a bit easier to maintain too ;)

Comment: can i ask you another question about this? not sure whether to add it to here or not....

Comment: If it expands on the details of this question, then I would say here. If it is more of a new question, I would suggest creating a new question and having a link to this one for the background if it is needed.

Comment: was basically how to set it up so that the end-user can choose the week from a list and it then displays the details for that week.

i can do it for a single day, but not sure how to pass a start and end date (which would be set as per weekly calendar) to it.